# Why flutter not using Set State with mounted checking + Future.delayed(Duration.zero) by default?

Tags: flutter

sometimes, i get bad state when using `setState( (){  } )`. and this solution fix that problem

```
  void refresh(Function func){
    if (this.mounted) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        this.setState(() {
          func();
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

so, my qustion is why Flutter not using that method by default? any pros and cons by using that method?

Answer (score 0):

You get bad state when you try to use `setState` while the flutter is building widgets for that screen. AFAIK `this.mounted` ensures that anything inside that `if` code block will get executed only after the widgets are laid on the screen.